# How do I display my logo while my ndroid app is loading

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to display an image (logo) while and android app is loading. I have been trying for two days with your but am unable to get is to show. This is my main activity:

```
package com.identykidz.identyalert

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.app.DownloadManager
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.Environment
import android.view.ContextMenu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.view.View
import android.webkit.*
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.core.content.FileProvider
import com.onesignal.OneSignal
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.net.URL
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.ImageView


const val ONESIGNAL_APP_ID = "KEY"

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

private lateinit var webView: WebView
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
private lateinit var overlayView: View
private lateinit var logoImageView: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // Initializing other views
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
    overlayView = findViewById(R.id.overlay_view)
    logoImageView = findViewById(R.id.logoImageView)
    //Initializing OneSignal
    Thread {
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE)
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this)
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)
        OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications()
    }.start()

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

    configureWebViewSettings()
    setWebViewClient()
    setWebChromeClient()

    runOnUiThread {
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.example.com/App/AppHome.php")
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        showLoader() // Show loader before navigating back
        webView.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

private fun showLoader() {
    overlayView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    logoImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE  // Show your logo
}

private fun hideLoader() {
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    overlayView.visibility = View.GONE
    logoImageView.visibility = View.GONE  // Hide your logo
}

private fun configureWebViewSettings() {
    val webSettings: WebSettings = webView.settings
    webSettings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webSettings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
    } else {
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
    }
    webSettings.blockNetworkImage = false
    webSettings.allowFileAccess = false
    webSettings.mixedContentMode = WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_NEVER_ALLOW
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
        webSettings.safeBrowsingEnabled = true
    }
    webSettings.setDisplayZoomControls(false)
    webSettings.allowContentAccess = false
    webSettings.allowFileAccess = false
    webSettings.cacheMode = WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE
}

private fun setWebViewClient() {
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
            showLoader() // Show loader and overlay before navigating
            webView.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
            return true
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            if (webView.progress == 100) {
                hideLoader() // Hide loader and overlay only after page finishes loading
            }
        }
    }
}


private fun configureWebView() {
    val webView = findViewById<WebView>(R.id.webView)
    overlayView = findViewById(R.id.overlay_view)

    // Set WebView client
    webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
        override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView, request: WebResourceRequest): Boolean {
            showOverlay()
            webView.loadUrl(request.url.toString())
            return true
        }

        override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
            hideOverlay()
        }
    }
}

private fun showOverlay() {
    overlayView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}

private fun hideOverlay() {
    overlayView.visibility = View.GONE
}

private fun setWebChromeClient() {
    registerForContextMenu(webView)
    webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
        override fun onShowFileChooser(
            webView: WebView?,
            filePathCallback: ValueCallback<Array<Uri>>?,
            fileChooserParams: FileChooserParams?
        ): Boolean {
            return true
        }
    }
}

override fun onCreateContextMenu(menu: ContextMenu?, v: View?, menuInfo: ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo?) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo)
    val hitTestResult = (v as WebView).hitTestResult
    if (hitTestResult.type == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
        hitTestResult.type == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE
    ) {
        menu?.add(0, 1, 0, "Save or share notification")
    }
}

fun takeScreenshot(view: View): String? {
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.width, view.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    view.draw(canvas)

    val screenshotFile = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "screenshot.png")
    try {
        val fos = FileOutputStream(screenshotFile)
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos)
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
        return screenshotFile.absolutePath
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    return null
}

override fun onContextItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    if (item.itemId == 1) {
        val result = webView.hitTestResult
        if (result.type == WebView.HitTestResult.IMAGE_TYPE ||
            result.type == WebView.HitTestResult.SRC_IMAGE_ANCHOR_TYPE
        ) {
            val imageUrl = result.extra
            if (!imageUrl.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                showImageOptionsDialog(imageUrl)
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No valid image URL found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        return true
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item)
}

private fun showImageOptionsDialog(imageUrl: String) {
    val options = arrayOf("Download", "Share External")

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Choose an action")
        .setItems(options) { dialog, which ->
            when (which) {
                0 -> downloadImage(imageUrl)
                1 -> shareImageExternal(imageUrl)
            }
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

    val dialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}


private fun shareImageExternal(imageUrl: String) {
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE // Show the ProgressBar

    // Start a background thread to download and share the image
    Thread {
        // Download the image and get the local file path
        val imageFilePath = downloadImageLocally(imageUrl)

        runOnUiThread {
            // Check if the file was downloaded successfully
            if (!imageFilePath.isNullOrBlank()) {
                // Create a content URI from the file path
                val imageFile = File(imageFilePath)
                val imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                    this,
                    applicationContext.packageName + ".provider",
                    imageFile
                )

                // Create an Intent to share the image
                val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                shareIntent.type = contentResolver.getType(imageUri)
                shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri)
                shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)

                // Start the sharing activity
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Image External"))
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to download and share the image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            progressBar.visibility = View.GONE // Hide the ProgressBar after the action is performed
        }
    }.start()
}


private fun downloadImage(imageUrl: String) {
    val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(imageUrl))
        .setTitle("Image Download")
        .setDescription("Downloading")
        .setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        .setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
        .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,
            "image.${getFileExtension(imageUrl)}"
        )

    val downloadManager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
    downloadManager.enqueue(request)

    Toast.makeText(this, "Downloading IdentyAlert Notification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

private fun downloadImageLocally(imageUrl: String): String? {
    try {
        val connection = URL(imageUrl).openConnection()
        connection.connect()
        val input = connection.getInputStream()

        val imageFile = File.createTempFile("shared_image", ".png", cacheDir)
        val output = FileOutputStream(imageFile)
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var bytesRead: Int

        while (input.read(buffer).also { bytesRead = it } != -1) {
            output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead)
        }

        output.close()
        input.close()

        return imageFile.absolutePath
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
        return null
    }
}

private fun getFileExtension(url: String): String {
    val mimeTypeMap = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton()
    val extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url)
    return mimeTypeMap.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension)?.split("/")?.get(1) ?: "jpg"
}
```

}

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/identy_alert"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-2dp" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/overlay_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/grey_overlay"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-2dp" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/IdentyGrey"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@drawable/identy_alert_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/identy_alert_icon"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.IdentyTheme"
    tools:targetApi="31">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IdentyTheme">

        <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.EnableSafeBrowsing" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.webkit.WebView.MetricsOptOut" android:value="true" />

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

</application>

</manifest>
```

I have tried to create a `showLogo()` function, but without success:

```
private lateinit var webView: WebView
private lateinit var progressBar: ProgressBar
private lateinit var overlayView: View
private lateinit var logoImageView: ImageView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    // Initializing other views
    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
    overlayView = findViewById(R.id.overlay_view)
    logoImageView = findViewById(R.id.logoImageView)
    //Initializing OneSignal
    Thread {
        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.VERBOSE, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.NONE)
        OneSignal.initWithContext(this)
        OneSignal.setAppId(ONESIGNAL_APP_ID)
        OneSignal.promptForPushNotifications()
    }.start()

    webView = findViewById(R.id.webView)
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)

    configureWebViewSettings()
    setWebViewClient()
    setWebChromeClient()
    logoImageView = findViewById(R.id.logoImageView)
    runOnUiThread {
        showLogo()
        webView.loadUrl("https://www.identykidz.com/IdentyAlert/AppHome.php")
    }
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    if (webView.canGoBack()) {
        showLoader() // Show loader before navigating back
        webView.goBack()
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}

private fun showLogo(){
    logoImageView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}


private fun showLoader() {
    overlayView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE
    
}

private fun hideLoader() {
    progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    overlayView.visibility = View.GONE
    
}
```

The `imageView` for the `showLogo()`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/identy_alert_logo"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

What am I missing?
The images are in the `res/drawable` folder, the names are correct.
I have resized the image to test.

Comment: You should use the splash screen library. This is standardized now. Look it up in the official Android developer documentation.